# how to do free scrolling with pixi.js or jquery ui?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, frontend, pixi.js

I am trying to make a page similar to https://pharrellwilliams.com/ with the free scroll that has to be able to navigate to the left right down and up, I do not know if it is done with a canvas

What I could investigate is that it occupies the libraries https://www.pixijs.com also https://jqueryui.com/

on the page of jquery iu is this example:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
```

with this code I can move the div where I want, but what I want is to mobilize as in the page of pharrell williams, I have an equal project and I would like to learn

Comment: Likely, this is done examining the mouse position and performing a scroll action when the mouse is in a specific target area. Please provide a example of what you have tried or a better idea of your code that you are trying to work with.

Comment: Looking at the source code, it does use a canvas element. Most likely, this is populated or redrawn as the mouse moves over it and the viewport is centered as the mouse moves around. Plus there are a LOT of JS Libraries in use, more than the 2 you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that might help you. It's far less intensive than the example site you provided. If this works for you, you can integrate it with your own project.

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
  <div class="part" style="background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.25); top: 0; left:0;"></div>
  <div class="part" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.25); top: 0; left: 1500px;"></div>
  <div class="part" style="background-color: rgba(255,255,0,0.25); top: 900px; left: 0;"></div>
  <div class="part" style="background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.25); top: 900px; left: 1500px;"></div>
</div>
```

Basic structure that creates 4 large div parts and specifically places them in the HTML. We can place items into the negative portion of the page, yet we can't scroll negative to 0 in either direction, so best to place them from 0,0.

**CSS**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#main {
  position: relative;
}

.part {
  width: 1500px;
  height: 900px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

This helps us hide the scroll bars and set other general styling.

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  function moveToCenter() {
    var vert = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
    var horz = $(document).width() - $(window).width();
    console.log("Centering View:", Math.round(horz / 2), Math.round(vert / 2));
    window.scrollTo(Math.round(horz / 2), Math.round(vert / 2));
  }

  function calcEdges(buff) {
    var t = [0, buff];
    var b = [$(window).height() - buff, $(window).height()];
    var l = [0, buff];
    var r = [$(window).width() - buff, $(window).width()];
    return {
      top: t,
      left: l,
      right: r,
      bottom: b
    };
  }

  function move(d, n) {
    var c, g;
    if (d == "top") {
      c = $(window).scrollTop();
      g = c + n;
      if (g <= 0 || (g >= $(document).height())) {
        console.log("Hit Top/Bottom Boundry");
        return false;
      }
      $(window).scrollTop(g);
    } else {
      c = $(window).scrollLeft();
      g = c + n;
      if (g <= 0 || (g >= $(document).width())) {
        console.log("Hit Left/Right Boundry");
        return false;
      }
      $(window).scrollLeft(g)
    }
  }

  function init() {
    moveToCenter();
    var sides = calcEdges(30);
    $(window).mousemove(function(e) {
      var x = e.clientX,
        y = e.clientY;
      if (x > sides.left[0] && x < sides.left[1]) {
        console.log("Dir: Left", x);
        move("left", -5);
      } else if (x > sides.right[0] && x < sides.right[1]) {
        console.log("Dir: Right", x);
        move("left", 5);
      }
      if (y > sides.top[0] && y < sides.top[1]) {
        console.log("Dir: Top", y);
        move("top", -5);
      } else if (y > sides.bottom[0] && y < sides.bottom[1]) {
        console.log("Dir: Bottom", y);
        move("top", 5);
      }
    });
  }
  init();
});
```

Fair amount going on here. here are the basics:

- a function to move the viewport to center of our content. This way the User has places to scroll to
- a function that helps us calculate where the "edges" are based on a specific number of pixels from the edge of the window
- a function to move or scroll the window in a specific direction (`top` or `left`) a specific amount
- a function to initialize everything, scroll to center and setup our `mousemove` callback events

Working Example Code: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/z8vh6kwx/

Working Example Show: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/z8vh6kwx/show

I have configured my example when the User moves the mouse 30 pixels from the edge of the screen it scrolls in that direction 5 pixels. It's a little clumsy, yet you can see it does work overall. You could have a number of Parts of different sizes and floating in different parts of the page. You can add other Hover styling and click events. it does not have to be any more complex than that.